# How to extend line features up to their intersection point in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, intersection, line

Is there a tool or plugin in QGIS to extend line features up to their intersection point?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CADDigitize now comes with a trim/extend function.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can do it with some of the CAD plugins of QGIS. For sure you can do it with Kosmo GIS http://opengis.es/

Select to linestrings which should be extended and use the Expand lines until crossing tool from the CAD toolbox. CAD Tools extension must be activated first from the Extension manager.

[image]

Click on the map.

[image]

For the second case use another CAD tool "Extend line"

[image]

Extend to nearby feature option suits for this use case

[image]

Click close to the line that should be connected

[image]